# android - using AdMob in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, admob

I know there are different questions to this task, but I don't get much information about it.
I found out that AdMob is part of firebase now, but there's a way to use it without firebase. Besides there are no tutorials or information about eclipse - is it necessary to use Android Studio or is it just not documented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it does not matter if it is part of Firebase, because all of it belongs to the **Google Play Services**. To get the AdMob classes, you just need to add `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1` to your **build.gradle** file (see the full list of all possible services [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)) which already explains your second question.
Android development in Eclipse is not supported any more. There is no Eclipse plugin any more. Google forces you to take Android Studio now.